# How to send a HTTP or XML/RPC request from SQL Server stored procedure/trigger?

Tags: sql-server, http, stored-procedures, triggers, xml-rpc

my client has SQL Server with some customer info and I am developing e-shop using MySQL database. What we need is to keep the database of customer loyalty points synchronized. When customer buys a product in an ordinary shop (not e-shop) these are recorded on SQL Server (via some accounting app). The problem is that I need this information to get to the MySQL server which stores information for the e-shop application, so the amount of loyalty points gets sync'ed on both servers.

Is there any way how can I send http and/or xml/rpc request from SQL Server via either trigger or stored procedure (I suppose trigger can trigger a stored procedure, so either of these is fine)?

Comment: Could you configure MSSQL to have the MySQL server as a "linked server"? http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,123221,123221

Comment: FYI you *can* do exactly what you asked for using something called [SQL Server CLR Integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345136(v=sql.90).aspx) however you **absolutely shouldn't!** Performing IPC (or any blocking IO) inside an SQL server process like this is likely to make a mess of your SQL Server instance because of the way threading works - you should use what Matthew suggests instead.

Answer (score 2):

Is it essential to interface with the MySQL DB via xml/rpc?

I might try to accomplish this by linking the MySQL DB to the MSSQL DB... the process will be version dependent so your MSSQL version is helpful...

But this site: 
http://www.infi.nl/blog/view/id/4/How_To_MySQL_as_a_linked_server_in_MS_SQL_Server

may be a good start for you

**EDIT:** And here, for MSSQL2008 
 
http://dbperf.wordpress.com/2010/07/22/link-mysql-to-ms-sql-server2008/

Comment: I did not know about this option but it looks like it is going to solve my problem in even more convenient way! Unfortunately, I can not try it right now as my customer haven't set up access to his server yet, but I went through the links and I can not see a reason why it shouldn't work. Thanks a lot!